# making matlab code android compatible

Tags: java, android, matlab

I have an image processing code in matlab containing its inbuilt functions like graythresh(), bwareaopen(),etc. I need to make that code processable on a smartphone(preferably with android os).The code also contains methods of image segmentation like Otsu. It would be of great help if you could suggest me the best and easy way to do that. I know elementary Java, but I do not know much about android programming.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. The best things to do is to port your code in java or port your code to use [openCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).
2. Use [Matlab coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/index.html) to generate C code. This C code doesn't require the MCR, and could be compiled to run directly on Android

Comment: Can you give me a bit of detail on how to port the code?Also,i have heard that the Matlab coder is expensive and not available for the student version.Is that true?

Comment: I mean use only android sdk to do your processing. This mean implement matlab specific functions such as graythresh and bwareaopen. Or you could use android sdk and openCV a libreary for image processing (compatible with android).

Comment: Do i need to own an android phone for that?Or can I do it using the emulator?

Comment: It's possible to test in emulator but it will be slow and sometime emulator is not representative of a real device.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the very handy Octave for Android:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octave&hl=en

It may not have all of the functions you need (as it is Octave, and a port) but it will be a good start.

Comment: I donot have an android device as of now.Can you tell me what is the best thing for me to do in the meantime?

Comment: You could check whether your code runs in Octave - http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/ - and if not, read about Octave and modify your code accordingly. Why are you asking about it now if you can't test?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am working on a project where it is needed.My phone is at the repairing shop,will get it back few days later.